# Check if method return type is based on generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, methodinfo

When I have a MethodInfo how can I check if the return type is based on a generic parameter?

```
public class GenericClass<T>
{
  public class InnerClass 
  {
    public static T A()
    {
      return default(T);
    }
  }       
}
```

When I check

```
typeof(GenericClass<>.InnerClass).GetMethod("A").ReturnType.IsGenericParameter
```

I get `true` but what if I only have a (closed) MethodInfo of a `GenericClass<int>` for example? Do I have to walk up the path of nested types and check if one has `IsGeneric == true` then get the GenericTypeDefinition of this type then walk the path down by instantiating open Types until I can create an open version of the MethodInfo or is there an easier (and faster) way?

Comment: Please explain your "what if" scenario with relevant code. Preferably also explain why you need this, so "is there an easier (and faster) way" can be properly answered.

Comment: @CodeCaster The reason why I want this because I want to know upfront if there can be different return types for a method for caching reasons and not finding out later when suddendly the ReturnType is different after the tenth call of A when GenericClass<string>.InnerClass.A is called for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stand corrected...

Given:

```
public class GenericClass<T1>
{
    public class InnerClass<T2>
    {
        public static Tuple<T1, T2, T3> A<T3>()
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

Type type = typeof(GenericClass<int>.InnerClass<long>);
var methodInfo = type.GetMethod("A");

MethodInfo method = (MethodInfo)type.Module.ResolveMethod(methodInfo.MetadataToken);
```

[Here](https://www.re-motion.org/blogs/mix/2009/08/12/trying-to-resolve-a-method-in-a-closed-generic-type) it was considered a problem... I use it as a feature :-)

Comment: Great, this seems like an easy way to immediately get the open version if available. Works also for 'normally' generic methods like A<T>.